# How to Optimize View With Union All

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a view with two separate queries with a union all. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS

SELECT foo.id, bar.data
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id

UNION ALL

SELECT baz.id, baz.data
FROM baz
```

I then run a select statement against the view like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE id = 1
```

The id of 1 only exists in the first select statement. The one with the `foo` and `bar` tables, but the union with the `baz` table is still causing it to run slower. It is faster if take out the union. I have to leave it there though, because sometimes an id will be used that will return results from the second select statement.

My question is: Is there any way to help sql server know that there are no results in the second part of the union all, so it doesn't have to run that query?

All of this data used to be in one table. This is a new data structure and all of our older applications will be relying on this view to read data from this new data structure. This is why we don't know which table will actually have the results beforehand.

Comment: If you know beforehand the row you're looking for is from the first table, query that directly

Comment: BTW, if you're real query is similar to this, don't even include `foo`, use `bar` directly, it has all the data you need.

Comment: No this is just an example. In reality there are fields we need from both tables. I made an edit explaining why I don't know beforehand which table will have the results we need.

Comment: do you have index on Id fields in all 3 tables? if so, you should not see any performance issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do a conditional union join. Try to see if it helps speed up the query by looking up the execution plan. Maybe is your bottle neck not exactly where you think?

```
SELECT foo.id, bar.data
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id

UNION ALL

SELECT baz.id, baz.data
FROM baz
WHERE baz.id = @idSearched
```

Sproc with a parameter might do trick in lieu of a view if you aren't going to do any editing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procName 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@id INT = 1
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT foo.id, bar.data
 FROM foo
 INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id

 UNION ALL

 SELECT baz.id, baz.data
 FROM baz
 WHERE baz.id = @id
END
GO
```

If you absolutely need a view like table, implement a stored function in the following kind of format:

```
CREATE FUNCTION v_emp (@pintEno INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
   SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp_id=@pintEno;
This allows you to use it as a normal view, with:
--Query it like :
SELECT * FROM v_emp(10)
```

Comment: All of your solutions would require me to rewrite every application that accesses this view to basically not use a view. That's not something I can do right now. I am looking for a way to optimize the view and have it return the same results it does now.

Comment: What's the outcome of your execution plan? The function create can replace your view entirely if you name it the same thing.

Comment: Also.. look into HAVING clause. 
SELECT * FROM MyView 
HAVING id = 1

Compare execution plans

Answer (score -1):

Do you have an index on `baz(id)`?  I would expect an index to be used for this query:

```
SELECT foo.id, bar.data
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
UNION ALL
SELECT baz.id, baz.data
FROM baz
WHERE baz.id;
```

Comment: Yes, it's the primary key, so there's a clustered index on it. However, it has about 16 million records, so it still slows down the query a little bit. I was hoping there was some way to make it realize that it didn't need to run that part of the query at all.

Comment: This is identical as what was submitted above. See SQL embedded in sproc.

Comment: @rgvassar . . . How does it slow down the query?  Looking up a record in a primary key index and *not* finding it should take very little time.  What difference in performance are you seeing?

Comment: It's definitely using the key in both instances. But when I take off the union all and everything after it is faster, and the execution plan is different.

Comment: @rgvassar . . . You should edit the question with the two execution plans.  It is hard to see how the query could be noticeably slower.

Comment: @rgvassar  I have`t seen negative vote for @GordonLinoff, even here he is correct. there is something wrong happening with your query or
server may be but accurate Answer show the
    Execution plan please.